# Send user to user notification Onesignal with after 5.0.0 version for Android

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I'm using below codes before 5.0.0 version of OneSignal and it was worked properly. After i update onesignal version, i get error and i cannot find any solution for Android.

```
    OneSignal.postNotification(new JSONObject("{'contents': {'en':'" + message +"'}, 'include_player_ids': ['" + RefModel.getInstance().friendID + "']}"),
            new OneSignal.PostNotificationResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "postNotification Success: " + response.toString());
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("OneSignalExample", "postNotification Failure: " + response.toString());
                }
            });
```